# How to intercept all request with cypress to test the response status

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I looking for a way to intercept all request in cypress.
I'm thinking about a thing like that:

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept({method: 'GET', path: '*'}).as('get')
    cy.intercept({method: 'POST', path: '*'}).as('post')
 })
```

then:

```js
 afterEcah(() => {
    cy.wait('@get').its('response.statusCode').should('be.oneOf', [200, 304])
    cy.wait('@post').its('response.statusCode').should('be.oneOf', [200, 304, 201])
 })
```

My problem is sometime in my test i don't have a get or a post request, so my test fail.

Maybe i need a condition is my `afterEach()` but i can' t figure it out.

Or perhaps the problem is using `afterEach()` for this purpose.

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Can you elaborate on your workflow? I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Using `afterEach()` ensures that the calls are only intercepted _after_ the test is executed.

Comment: The idea is to be able to intercept all request, for example all GET request and control the response status is 200 or 304.

Comment: You will need to have some idea of all of the calls that you want to intercept. `cy.intercept` will only intercept one call at a time -- so if you have three calls that meet some criteria, you'd need to use `cy.intercept` three times. Additionally, you will need to have those during your test, and not in the `afterEach`, unless those calls happen after the test has completed.

Answer (score 1):

For all requests, you can put your code into `cypress/support/e2e.js` file:

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept({method: 'GET', path: '*'}).as('get')
    cy.intercept({method: 'POST', path: '*'}).as('post')
 })
```